# Are there clear counter-examples to this definition of mathematics?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

Here I'll re-present the question about a definition of mathematics as being about deduction, that I've given in a prior [posting](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/59410/are-there-counter-examples-to-this-broad-characterization-of-mathematics), but here I'll further clarify that this might not be what is usually known about that term, I mean "deduction". Here before I'll go to that I'll present what I believe it to be the two main sources of factual verification attainable to us humans, that is the :empirical and analytic. 
A factual empirical proof is an observation or otherwise a consistent result of experimentation under controlled conditions. This is factual evidence as present to the senses. The other source of factual evidence, i.e. of truths, is the analytic source which begs no empirical validation at all, i.e. it is empirical free, and philosophical free, i.e. not subject to philosophical debate, it merely depends on controlled string manipulation substitution rules (I'll call those inference rules), example: All bald men are bald. No one needs to go see all bald men and check whether they are bald or not in order to verify such a statement. Another example of such a string manipulation is reciprocity, i.e. if at rule 1 x is replaced by y, and at rule 2 y is replaced by x, then if we apply rules 1 then 2 to object x we get x. A simple rule following symbolic substitution game. Of course we can begin with any strings of symbols, define any amount of manipulation rules, and then define a symbolic system as the closure of all strings of symbols under the specified inference rules, the resulting system is a set of all strings of symbols so obtained. I'll call such a system generally as a "symbolic deductive system". Now a "deductive proof" is a minimal subset of a deductive system in which every string in it is derived by an inference rule from a string in it. Of course axioms are strings derived by 'stipulation rules', [i.e. stipulated directly to be in the system], a privilege not offered to any string in the system. Now deductive provability in this general sense is what is meant by "Analytic fact", in other worlds the fact is the statement that if such and such strings belongs to a specified deductive system then such and such strings also belong to it. Not only that it can also include a specific assignment of "meaning" in an exact manner to the symbols of that system, and so the result would also be analytic for that meaning, i.e. the fact would be if such and such sentences in the system are about meaning such and such, then it follows that sentences such and such would be in the system and it would be about meaning such and such. Of course the specification of a deductive system is by specifying its inference rules and the primary string of symbols, i.e. those privileged to be derivable by stipulation rules, and sometimes the specific meanings attached to its symbols especially the axioms. The meaning assigned to a deductive system, i.e. it's semantics, is considered as "part" of the deductive system.

I'm personally not aware of a standard of factual knowledge other than being either empirically validated or analytically validated. What I mean here by "factual" is having high degree of certainty about it that the endeavor of opposing it is a negligible quest. Of course there are other kinds of knowledge some might be based on extensively trained philosophical insights like in metaphysics, ethics, epistemology, etc..., I'm not sure if such matters bear a kind of certainty about some of its material similar to that in empirical and analytic spheres, I think there should be some!? supposing that some do, then those are pretty much complex and definitely non-trivial extra-analytic pieces of knowledge. Also proofs by appeal to "intuition" about extra-analytic matters, are extra-analytic, while argumentation based on intuition about deductive systems that are not based on non-trivial extra-analytic provability, are considered an intuition about analytic matters, although in itself is not an analytic fact, yet it is permitted to be the basis of axioms for pure mathematical systems (see below).

Now the main question that I want to answer is what is the definition of mathematics? in other words what is subject matter of mathematics? i.e. mathematics is the study of ...? what we are to put in the blank? Botany is the study of "plants", Astronomy is the study of "Celestial objects", Medicine is the study of "management of diseases", pretty much specific subject matters. The question here is more about what "Pure Mathematics" is really about.

My answer to this is that ***Pure Mathematics is the study of what takes part in non trivial deductive systems whose axioms, inference rules and definitions are all not the results of provability by non-trivial extra-analytic methods***.

*Applied mathematics* is defined by exactly the same definition above but with removing "not" from it.

Now ***Mathematics*** in the most general sense is ***the study of what takes part in non trivial deductive systems***.

It's important to realize that the definition given here to "deduction" is not the traditional one, the traditional one is about *sentences* when the inferential rules are *logical*. While here this method applies to any exact way of specifying a string of symbols, including individual symbols, terms, diagram sketching, model representations,..any piece of syntax, so an inference rule can be a function on any piece of syntax, not necessarily being functions on "sentences" as it is usually held. Actually we can even have inference rules being non-functions, i.e. having multiple outputs, so they are definable relations on pieces of syntax, whatever those pieces were, but they must be exactly specifiable. It is also important to realize that the sentential inference rules (and therefore sentential deduction) can be extra-logical also, provided that they are exact! I think this would be the widest possible definition of "deduction", that might be even undesirable in some sense.

Also to be understood is that once we've said "study" we mean treatment of all aspects involved in the definition, so the informal reasoning leading to axioms, definitions, inferences, etc.. are all involved in this study of course, as long as the result at the end abide by the definitions given above, as well is the technical manipulations involved with the study of having good terminology, clear processing, etc...

My question here: are there clear counter-examples to this definition?

Comment: I don't understand why you want your definition to apply to strings rather than sentences, given that sentences can be understood as well formed strings (given some syntactic rules) and that we wouldn't expect mathematics to apply to non-well formed strings. Also it seems to me that you're trying to reinvent the wheel. Why don't you start by reading some philosophy of mathematics?

Comment: Otherwise I don't see any clear counterexample to your definition (it's just that I see no reason why you don't start from the standard definitions of deductive system)

Comment: reach the discussion present in the posting I'v referred and you'll understand what I mean. There is no re-invention of the wheal here. Not any well formed sting of symbols is a sentence. We need the definition of mathematics to directly articulate all of what is written in mathematics old and present in their original forms.

Comment: How do you understand strings of symbols and sentences? I wouldn't count diagrams as strings of symbols because they are structured so if your purpose was to include reasoning on diagrams I think it doesn't do the job.

Comment: by a diagram I mean a sketch, an object that we draw, it is a piece of syntax to me, we can indeed break it down syntactically, and I think we can have manipulation rules (i.e. inferences) deriving its structure. If not then please give me a counter-example, so that I can fathom your objection

Comment: You can describe a diagram using strings of symbols but a diagram is not a string of symbols. For example if you draw a circle and an inscribed triangle, the diagram represents specific relations between the circle and the triangle but the relations are not represented symbolically (there's no symbol in the diagram that directly corresponds to the relation "being inscribed", rather the fact that the points of the triangle lie on the circle is relevant, but this fact is not represented by a symbol).

Comment: but this seems to me to be a simple forward inference. just write the inference as: the inference line and to the right of it write Inscribe and above the line is a circle and a triangle (i.e. the inputs) written as separate non overlapping figures, then below the line is the circle with the triangle inside it with all of its points lying on the circle. did I miss something?

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. My point is that in a diagram some relations/information are encoded graphically (not symbolically) and I'm not talking about a mathematical inference here, but about what could be the premise of an argument (the equivalent of the sentence "let ABC be a triangle inscribed in a circle C"), so I don't understand why you mention inferences. Inferences come after, once the diagram is given. One option is to say: the diagram is merely a psychological support, but math is really about sentences. I would agree with this solution. But apparently it's not what you say.

Comment: This contains all the mistakes I already told you about, along with confused choice of terminology, so I am not sure why you thought it would do any better than the original.

Comment: @QuentinRuyant, now if lets leave the complex question about diagramatic inferences, and lets take simple algorthmic procedures like the direct move from 789 + 126 to 915 this can be viewed as a direct move from a two place function symbol which is a term (not a sentence) to a constant, the algorithm doing that can be broken down into sequential inferential steps that starts from the term (789 + 126) down to end in the constant 915, these inferential steps are functions on terms. One can do all of that with sentences, but a direct detour is nice to capture.

Comment: @Conifold, No you had obvious errors in your reply, especially those concerned with the use of Godel's incompleteness theorems. I'm simply not convinced by your replies. And I think the choice of  terminology is correct.

Comment: @QuentinRuyant, the equivalent of the sentence "let ABC be a triangle inscribed in a circle C" in the direct term inference is simply the inscribed diagram itself, what else it would be? it itself graphically encodes this inscribing? Am I missing something? I don't understand really what you mean what could be the premise of an argument? which argument you are referring to? is it an argument whose premise is "let a triangle ABC be inscribed into circle C"? is that what you are asking about, for example we have that premise and another premise stating if the base of ABC is the diameter of C,

Comment: continuation..., then ABC is a right triangle. All this information can be encoded in ONE diagram, which demonstrates all of that, without a clear hint of an inference order, hmmm... I mean all the information seem to be presented in one time. Of course we can use coloring to denote the direction of inferential flow, so the darker a shade the more recent it is, so the circle would be the fainter then the triangle, then its points, then its base, then the right angle being the darkest. Or we simply number those. Those would be flow diagrams that reflect the inferential flow.

Comment: Terminology is "correct" when it allows others to understand you: "deductive system" which is not deductive, "axioms" which are not axioms, "faithfully grasp" which is... I am not really sure what, do not. Unfortunately, what you "mean" is not what comes out. But, perhaps, you need to hear it from others.

Comment: @Conifold, to me I'm satisfied with this definition, I didn't see any clear counter-example, neither from your nor others did present anyone yet, once I see a clear one, I'll modify it. As about terminology, it is an insignificant matter, I defined my terms, so even if it is not the best one, i think it meets its purpose, and that's what really matters!

Comment: If the purpose is only to satisfy yourself then what is the point of asking others? As is, *all* of mathematics is a counterexample to what you wrote, I wouldn't venture to guess whether it is so for what you *mean*. "Redefining" words does not change associations they have, even in your own mind. Your insistence on "deductions" and "axioms", as well as the overall text, suggest that you are still thinking about them along the old templates, no matter what you say you "defined". Try an exercise: express yourself without using those words, and see if it works.

Comment: @Conifold, how all of mathematics is a counter-example?? this is just a blinded assertion. Clearly arithmetic, geometry all abide by what I wrote, they can be even interpretable in the ordinary deductive systems which are subsystems of what I wrote. Anyhow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89410/discussion-between-zuhair-and-conifold).

Comment: Yes the diagram is equivalent to the sentence but it's not a string of symbols, that's my point. So if your purpose is to include reasoning on diagrams in your definition of math it's not working. If you view diagrams as mere psychological tools you're fine though (and technically speaking, 789+126=915 is a sentence, on the technical sense of sentence). Sorry I'm not interested in continuing this discussion. Hope you see my point. I would still advise you to study phil of math instead of coming with your own system/definitions if you're willing to take advice. Cheers

Comment: Bad examples. All bald men are bald. What do you consider bald ? A few visible hairs count ? Shaved counts ? It's nothing mathematically exact in this statement.

Comment: @QuentinRuyant, thanks for the remark, I understand it now, I meant that we can use some kinds of diagrams and not reasoning about all kinds of diagrams, some diagrams can be represented in a sequential manner in a way as to permit us using them as  an inferential tool. Actually I agree with your remarks in general, even I agree that I can restrict this definition to just the sentential inferential rule, i.e. the ordinary deductive systems in Hilbert's style, but I just wanted the definition to be more generous, but I agree it is in some sense redundant. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Overmind, well it might be indeed a bad example, I wanted it to be just an example of the general rule $\phi(x) \wedge \psi(x) \to \phi(x)$, now it doesn't matter how do you define bald, as long as the same definition is used for the antecedent and the consequent! the statement is correct.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89429/discussion-on-question-by-zuhair-are-there-clear-counter-examples-to-this-defini).

Comment: Your definition sounds almost like it might be a definition of logic itself. Perhaps it would help if you explained how your view differs from logicism.

Comment: Logicism try to reduce mathematical statements into pure logical ones, i.e. to a deductive system having all of its primitives, inferential rules, all being logical. This definition doesn't claim that. It doesn't say that ALL deductive mathematical systems that uses extra-logical primitives can be interpreted in a pure logical system, that's the difference.

Comment: although it is not easy to give a definition of "logical primitive", yet in general a logical primitive is a concept purely related to enacting deductions in deductive systems of the most general sort, like the known logical connectives and the quantifiers, the variables, constants, symbols from which logic is written and the logical inference rule etc..  Now everything other than those is an extra-logical concept, where it has a specific content other than just enacting rules, like with the known mathematical operators, set membership, part-hood symbol, etc...

Comment: The distinction you make between logical and extra-logical primitives is a contentious one. On some accounts of what constitutes a logical constant, set membership would qualify. Much depends on your view of the status of higher order logics.

Answer (score 2):

> Pure Mathematics is about what can be proved deductively in a non trivial manner in deductive systems whose axioms, inference rules and definitions are all not the results of provability by non-trivial extra-analytic methods.

I don't mind that your definition falls prey to objections as "what is non-trivial?", "your definition of deductive is too broad" which of course it does.

Here are some other, in my opinion far more serious objections:

- **You are assuming that mathematics is definable, and even worse, that it needs a definition**

This is an implicit assumption which I have serious trouble finding arguments for. By the way, while it is easy to agree that botanists study plants, it is not so clear whether mathematicians study mathematics or whether whatever  mathematicians study is mathematics.

- **You don't define mathematics, you define (if anything at all) a part of mathematics that logic can make sense of**

No, mathematicians don't talk all day about proofs. They like ideas, nifty tricks, pathological counterexamples, clear exposition, good notation, useful applications and so on. This is part of what mathematicians think about/what they do, which means it is part of mathematics but you don't even mention these things.

- **You have a misunderstanding about what applied mathematics is**

In applied math, you seem to think, the axioms come somehow from outside mathematics. But there are plenty of cases in pure math, where central definitions are motivated from outside mathematics (for example symplectic geometry), and lots of cases that were considered pure, but after having found applications have partly turned into applied math (for example in graph theory, heck, even type theory).

- **Nobody cares what can be proven**

There are several aspects of this point.
Most mathematicians haven't seen a formal definition of proof. And they don't care, since they do not want to know what you can prove with the axioms of an abelian group, they want to know what is true in abelian groups.

But even this step from syntax to semantics won't help you everywhere. No group theorist would say he wants to know what properties in all groups hold. He has long recognised, that such a property is almost certainly trivial. He has set himself quite a different challenge, maybe how to meaningfully classify groups, or maybe just try to understand groups. Understand is something entirely different from knowing that it is true/being able to prove it.

And lastly, if something is not provable but should be so, it is simply going to be made provable. What does that tell you about the object of study?

<sub>These are only some rough points, I will try to elaborate a little bit when I find some more time.</sub>

Comment: as for symplectic geometry example, which I have no experience with at all, the motivation is from the outside, but was its premises non trivial particular results of empirical experimentation or observations? I mean for example something compared to the law of gravity. I don't think so. Arithmetic, geometry can be said to have extra-analytic motivation and even empirical ones, but those are trivial imports, they are not non-trivial results of empirical experimentation\observations or results of deep philosophical intriguing speculative thought or the alike.

Comment: as for the last question, the matter is about if it CAN be provable or not, if it can find a proof under some deductive system, then it belongs to the mathematical investigation if it proves to be a non-trivial quest. Whether it is applied or not? it depends on the axioms in question. You've raised a lot of other points, I'll respond to them once completed (i.e. after you find the time to complete presenting them).

Comment: Regarding the first objection, I don't see any grounds for leaving mathematics undefined!? why? on the contrary mathematics is so rigorous that one would like to see a definition of it! The other point you say it is not clear that what mathematicians study is mathematics? then why they were called mathematicians in the first place? by definition a mathematician is a person who do mathematics? you need to clarify your objection. About the second object which is about what mathematicians like, I think I already addressed this in my last comment, those are side matters, any discipline

Comment: continuation: .. has some technical matters associated with it like choosing good terminology, having a clear language, showing strange examples, etc.. this is not specific to mathematics, those are characteristic of any "STUDY", and I've alluded indirectly to those in my last passage. As for the third point, I don't think I've misunderstood applied math, I already commented on that, of course you can begin purely to end up having large parts of it useful in application, and vice verse, those matters are not against what I've said. The last point I think I've addressed it, it is not a matter

Comment: of what mathematicians like or not, it is a matter of what mathematics is. Even if mathematicians don't care to prove matters, that doesn't change the capability status of the matter they are reasoning about to be proved in deductive systems or not. Mathematicians can spent whatever time they want in demonstrating, sorting, understanding, etc.. yes they do all of those activities but about what material? Still they are demonstrating, sorting,..,etc a material that is capable of being proved in deductive systems. Now your point about triviality of something provable in all groups

Comment: I don't know why you've raised such a point, since I never said something like that, what is provable in a deductive system doesn't mean it is provable in all deductive systems? You can examine a particular subject in a deductive system and present proof about this particular subject, still it is a proof made in the deductive system even though it might not be a theorem over the whole domain of that system, that is something else, I didn't discriminate about provability in a system between these two conditions. You can reason in Geometry about circles only and prove matters related to those.

Comment: As far as I can see, I don't see a clear point against what I've presented in the head post.